# SSRS Report with Multi Valued Parameter returning blank page

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008, reporting-services, optional-parameters, multivalue

I have a report with 1 date parameter and 3 multi select parameters. The parameters are not designed to be cascading parameters (where parameter 3 depends on value of parameter 2, etc). I've designed the report so users can select all values or specific values for the parameters.

Here's my problem, in BIDS, when I test the report, all of the parameters work. When I deploy the report, although I select values (either all or specific) for the last parameter, when I run the report, SSRS returns a blank page, and my selections for the last multi value parameter are empty.

I've spent some time looking for a fix for this, but the posts I've seen aren't quite what I'm looking for. Can anyone offer some guidance on how I can fix this problem.

Comment: There's not enough detail here to determine what the problem is. Please include samples of the Available Values as well as your SQL where you apply the parameters. Also specify if you changed any parameter properties from the defaults.

Comment: I just saw this. Thank you for the comment. I'll prepare a sample and post later today.